# How do I eliminate even numbers from this python code without an infinite loop occurring?

Tags: python-2.7, import, sys

I have tried different ways to try print odd numbers only but its only causing an infinite loop to occur. Could you please assist me?

```
import sys

i = 1
while i < len(sys.argv):
    print sys.argv[i]
    i = i + 1
```

Comment: I'm guessing you are running this code by executing a python script and then providing the arguments?

Comment: also its `print(sys.argv[i])` not `print sys.argv[i]` according to python 3's syntax

Comment: maybe OP is on Python2.7

Comment: I tried this on python 3.10 and it works fine.. this is how Im calling it `python script.py arg1 arg2 arg3` and it prints `arg1` `arg2` `arg3` each on separate line.
I used print() function instead of print statement for python3. Nothing else was changed.

Comment: Yes I am doing this but whenever i add like if i % 2 == 1: it causes an infinite loop, any way to stop this

Comment: then the tag should be python-2.7 to specify it

Comment: sorry i am on python 2.7, i was told to stick to that by my teacher

Comment: why do you want to do `i%2 == 1`?

Comment: I thought thats how you get odd numbers, no?

Comment: On a side note, you can replace ```i = i + 1``` with ```i += 1``` which is more Pythonic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is little bit confusing.
You should be processing all arguments and then decide which one you should print.

```
import sys

i = 1
while i < len(sys.argv):
    number = int(sys.argv[i])
    if number % 2 == 1:
        print number
    i = i + 1
```

Comment: but see the problem with this is that my lecturer has made the numbers appear in the 1,3,5 place on one test and then 1,2,4 place in the second test

Comment: So then it prints even numbers aswell

Comment: oh ok. I got it.. So you want only odd numbers. Updated the answer with code changes,

Comment: ah now I see where I went wrong thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

In python, sys.argv contains only one item 'main.py' in index number 0.

So, if you run the program from index 1, you will get nothing as output. If you set it from index 0, you will get 'main.py' printed as output.

If this answer is not satisfactory,  please clarify your issue with this code.

Comment: Yes I understand that the reason why I started at 1 is because I dont want odd-arguments.py in the answer for example right now if I was to run my code with the command line arguments in the question it would print out for the first test 5 4 3 2 1 and the next test 23521 24373
25882
5878
22229

Comment: now is there a way to add to my code a parameter or statement to eliminate the even nnumbers from printing

Comment: In general,  if you try the following code, it will print all the odd numbers in a range. 

         print( [x for x in range(10) if x%2!=0] )